# Oracle, calling PL/SQL issues from within SQL-Plus file x.sql says my_function "may not be a function"

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, sqlplus

so simple, if I create my function as `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MD5_ENCODE` it will run smoothly, but if it stays anonymously within the SQL-Plus block as PL/SQL --> "may not be a function" error.

What is this Oracle "feature" again?

```
DECLARE

FUNCTION MD5_ENCODE(CLEARTEXT IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS    
    CHK VARCHAR2(16);   
    HEX VARCHAR2(32);  
    I   INTEGER;  
    C   INTEGER;  
    H   INTEGER;  
BEGIN
    IF CLEARTEXT IS NULL THEN
        RETURN '';
    ELSE
        CHK := DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(INPUT_STRING
=> CLEARTEXT);
        FOR I IN 1 .. 16 LOOP
            C := ASCII(SUBSTR(CHK, I, 1));
            H := TRUNC(C / 16);
            IF H >= 10 THEN
                HEX := HEX || CHR(H + 55);
            ELSE
                HEX := HEX || CHR(H + 48);
            END IF;
            H := MOD(C, 16);
            IF H >= 10 THEN
                HEX := HEX || CHR(H + 55);
            ELSE
                HEX := HEX || CHR(H + 48);
            END IF;
        END LOOP;  
        RETURN HEX;  
    END IF;  

END;  

BEGIN  
    UPDATE ADDRESSES_T SET STREET = MD5ENCODE(STREET) ;  

-- etc...  
END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=245112

There are a number of things it could be.

My #1 candidate is, we can only use functions in SQL statements that are public i.e. declared in a package spec. This is the case even for SQL statements executed within the same Package Body. The reson is that SQL statements are executed by a different engine which can only see publicly declared functions.

---

**Long story short**, *function must be defined in a package,* like CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MD5ENCODE(IN_TEXT IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS ...

Comment: -1 incorrect. You can call a function from SQL and it doesn't have to be in a package spec.

Comment: Contradicting @JeffreyKemp, this fixed me up. I added my function to the spec and suddenly I stopped getting "function FOO may not be used in SQL". If the function is not in the spec then it can only be called from pl/sql not from sql. SQL can only call public functions hence why it had to be in the spec.

Comment: Following up, here's an AskTom about this: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1895113969657

Comment: @Gabriel, I've been wrong before, but not this time. I said *"you can call a function from SQL and it doesn't have to be in a package spec"*. Try `CREATE FUNCTION myfunc RETURN NUMBER BEGIN RETURN 1; END;` and then run `SELECT myfunc FROM DUAL;`. It will work.

Comment: In other words, if you want to put the function in a package but call it from SQL, you must declare it in the package spec. *But*, you don't have to put the function in the package if you don't want to. You can create the function as a separate schema object on its own, outside the package.

Comment: Context is king. To your point, the OP didn't mention packages, so @yli's comment isn't 100% representative. Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 4):

In order to call a function within a SQL statement, it needs to exist as a function object within the database.  The SQL statement is parsed and executed separately from your PL/SQL code, so it doesn't have access to the locally defined function.

If you really don't want to create the function object, you could use a cursor to loop over the rows in the table, execute the function in a PL/SQL statement, and update each row as you go.

Comment: but I did the same thing with a PROCEDURE, with success.
why differently between PROCEDURE & FUNCTION?

Comment: You would have to show me an example of what you did.  As far as I know, you can't call a PROCEDURE within a SQL statement at all.

Comment: Detected the reason, as in: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=245112

There are a number of things it could be. 

My #1 candidate is, we can only use functions in SQL statements that are public i.e. declared in a package spec. This is the case even for SQL statements executed within the same Package Body. The reson is that SQL statements are executed by a different engine which can only see publicly declared functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is you have a typo.

> FUNCTION MD5_ENCODE(CLEARTEXT IN
>   VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

versus

> UPDATE ADDRESSES_T SET STREET =
>   MD5ENCODE(STREET) ;

You are missing the underscore in the function call in the update statement.

The next error you will encounter is :

```
PLS-00231: function 'MD5_ENCODE' may not be used in SQL
```

So you can simply assign the function results to a variable and use it in the Update statement.

Comment: not a typo error. I corrected it.
PLS-00231 "function 'md5encode' may not be used in SQL"

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned above comments, this could be useful.

```
DECLARE
  V NUMBER := 0;
  FUNCTION GET_SQ(A NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN A * A;
  END;
BEGIN
  V := GET_SQ(5);
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V);
  UPDATE MYTABLE A SET A.XCOL = V;
END;
```